# Check Abaqus version number

Tags: windows-console

I want to be able to run a simple command to retrieve the active version of Abaqus.

I had hoped that `abaqus -v` or `abaqus -version` would work. However, these commands are not valid.

Running `abaqus whereami` seems to do the trick:

> Abaqus 6.9-EF1 Abaqus
>   Site ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Abaqus is located in the directory C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.9-EF1
>   ...

However, this command is very **slow.** Querying the Site ID takes way too long.

Is there a quick way to get the version number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of CAE the python variable 'version' stores the current version number ie:

> > > version
> > >       '6.12-1'

Comment: Now if I could run the Abaqus Python interpreter outside of the CAE.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is as close as I am going to get.

Comment: Note that `abaqus cae nogui` counts against your licence. `abaqus python` is free, but does not load CAE components.

Answer (score 5):

In command prompt you can get abaqus to return the version by typing:

```
abaqus information=release
```

This returns abaqus version number and the location. Though does include the site ID so is not that fast.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following command in windows console(cmd):

`abaqus information=versions`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to explicitly get version in a Python script:

```
import abaqus
version = abaqus.version
```

Answer (score -2):

Run the following command in the command prompt at the bottom of Abaqus GUI

```html
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
```